# How to generate a propensity score for a continuous treatment in R?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, propensity-scores, lavaan

I would like to generate a propensity score for a **continuous** treatment in R, and then control for the propensity score in a structural equation model (using the *lavaan* package). I'm aware that the *twangContinuous* package can generate propensity scores for continuous treatments, but it doesn't seem there is an option for extracting the propensity score to control for it (or weight analyses) in structural equation models. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try Walter Leites book "Practical PS methods in R" (https://www.practicalpropensityscore.com/). Good luck.

Comment: Are you trying to include the propensity score as a covariate? That is not a recommended approach. Use the estimated weights to fit a weighted SEM and use robust standard errors or bootstrap the whole thing (recommended). `WeightIt` provides many more options to estimate weights for continuous treatments.

Comment: Thank you Stefan and Noah, those suggestions are very helpful